# HtmlUnit WebClient.getPage does not process javascript

Tags: javascript, java, htmlunit

I try to use HtmlUnit WebClient.getPage to load a page with javascript. But the loaded page does not process the javascript code in it.

I tried to add all the options in WebClient based on all related answers I can find. It still does not work.

```
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    String testUrl = "https://www.coursera.org/browse/data-science";
    try {
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(testUrl);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(20 * 1000);
        System.out.println(page.asXml());
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    webClient.close();
```

On the page "https://www.coursera.org/browse/data-science", I expect to see all the courses listed in the page.asXml() as html element. But it only shows the courses in the "Trending courses" section as html element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [htmlunit: return a completely loaded page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956952/htmlunit-return-a-completely-loaded-page)

Comment: I tried it. It still does not work. As you can see the loaded page have many courses. But page.asXml() only contains those on the "Trending courses" section. The other sections come from the javascript code. But it seems that those javascript code is never processed

Answer (score 1):

From a first look i think this is because the javascript failes (duplicate declaration of var t). You can see the error in the log. This does not fail with real browsers and might stop the required js processing and as an result only parts of the page are created.

Have analyzed the bug already a bit and i'm able to reproduce this in a simple scenario (this is usually the hardest step if this kind of huge js libs are involved). Will try to fix this in Rhino, but this will requiere some time.

Please open an issue at https://github.com/HtmlUnit with you test case. I will then take care of adding an issue and building a PR. If you like you can add a link to this question, then i will update this also. To be informed about any HtmlUnit updates you can use https://twitter.com/HtmlUnit.